# How does the phosphate ion look like?

Tags: bond, theoretical-chemistry, hybridization, covalent-compounds, vsepr-theory

I am trying to understand how a phosphate ion looks like using the VSEPR theory.

The phosphorus element has an atomic number of 15, and therefore it has a electron configuration as follow by the Aufbau principle.

$$\pu{1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p3}$$

It needs to have one π-bond with one oxygen atoms and 4 σ-bonds with all of the 4 oxygen atoms, so it is hybridizing 4 orbitals to form some hybridized orbital and leaving one p orbitals around for the pi bond? How does that work?

Comment: As a side note: there is no double bond in phosphate, only four $\ce{P-O}$ single bonds. Each oxygen carries a formal negative charge while phosphorus carries a formal positive charge. This leaves us with phosphorus being $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridised as (hopefully) expected.

Comment: @Jan - this is not a duplicate. That post you mentioned is about counting electrons, mine is about molecular shape.

Comment: I am confused, Wikipedia says phosphate has a P double bond O.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphate
Are you saying Wikipedia is wrong? It could be ...

Comment: Wikipedia is not *wrong*, it is just... a simplified representation, perhaps? It is tedious to draw the correct thing every time, so sometimes we fall back on simplified representations; as long as we know what it really means, then it is fine.

Comment: I marked as a dupe because once you get the bond counting right (you only need four single bonds) the structure explains itself and there is no need to look for a hypothetical orbital to make a hypothetical fifth bond.

Comment: It is kind of sad that the solution is removed. It was wrong, but a lot of discussion associated with it was useful.

I realize now that VSPER is an outdated theory and it cannot describe phosphate, what is a better one?